# OSGi: including extra system packages in Eclipse Equinox

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, equinox

In the Apache Felix OSGi framework, configuration files offer an option to include additional system packages in the Felix ecosystem. The line in the Felix config looks like this:

```
# To append packages to the default set of exported system packages,
# set this value.
org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra=gnu.java.net.local
```

I am switching my current OSGi framework from Felix to Eclipse Equinox, and I've found that one of my bundles depends on the `gnu.java.net.local` package that I previously had access to in Felix, but I can't find anything in the (vague) [configuration documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html) for Equinox
that seems equivalent to the setting in Felix. Does anyone know the Equinox way of including this extra package?

If you're looking at the link I shared above (to the Equinox configuration documentation), the "System Properties" section is the one that lists configuration file options. I'm not sure if there is a more complete documentation elsewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property you mentioned is available in every OSGi container. It is listed in the OSGi core specification. See chapter *4.2.2 Launching properties*.

You can define it in the config file of equinox or as a system property like:

```
java -jar equinox.jar -Dorg.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra=gnu.java.net.local
```

Comment: Thank you! You've given me some new reading material. I'm updating the build now, I'll report back with results. For anyone else looking for a link to the source, [here](http://www.osgi.org/download/r5/osgi.core-5.0.0.pdf) is the R5 Core Specification. The section in question begins on page 82.